# Return string with array Javascript

Tags: javascript

How can I insert both a string and an array to a return function and the array doesn't change??

```
function name(){
   let array = [1, 2, 3]
   return "Hello" + array  // I want Hello [ 1, 2, 3]
}
```

`return array` is equal to `[ 1, 2, 3 ]`.

But `return "Hello" + array`  is equal to `Hello1,2,3`.

What I want is `Hello [ 1, 2, 3 ]`

Comment: `'Hello' + JSON.stringify([1,2,3,])`

Answer (score 0):

Like that?

```
function name(){
   let array = [1, 2, 3]
   return "Hello [ " + array.join(', ') + " ]";  // I want Hello [ 1, 2, 3]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As said in the comments thanks to [`Jared Farrish`](https://stackoverflow.com/users/451969/jared-farrish), you can simply use

```js
'Hello' + JSON.stringify([1,2,3,])
```

For example

```js
let array = [1,2,3];
console.log(JSON.stringify([ 1, 2, 3])) // [ 1, 2, 3]
```

You can check more use of the function by clicking [`JSON.stringify`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify)